# Mysql grant limited by IPv6 subnet

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb

I want to permit access to a mysql server over IPv6 and limit access to the particular account to our ULA subnet we are using (`fdd7:03d7:6247::/48`).

The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) seems to suggest that wildcards are valid in the host when using IPv4, but how do you do this with IPv6?

> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example, 'user_name'@'%.example.com' applies to user_name for any host in the example.com domain, and 'user_name'@'192.168.1.%'.

I have tried all these values which seemed like they should be valid.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'zoredache'@'fdd7:3d7:6247::%'  IDENTIFIED BY  '...' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'zoredache'@'fdd7:3d7:6247:%'   IDENTIFIED BY  '...' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'zoredache'@'fdd7:03d7:6247:%'  IDENTIFIED BY  '...' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'zoredache'@'fdd7:03d7:6247::%' IDENTIFIED BY  '...' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Using the `%` only in the host field works, so I know I have the password, and server setup properly.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'zoredache'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY  '...' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The server has DNS resolution disabled with the `skip-name-resolve`, and I don't really want to enable it, and mess around with setting up reverse DNS zones for the ULA address space.

To repeat, how do I grant access for a user only if they connect from the  `fdd7:03d7:6247::/56` network?

Comment: I wish someone else would step in.  There are still several unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

`::`, as I understand IPv6 indicates as many chunks of all zero as are needed to fill out the full length.  The question comes as to whether MySQL treats `%` as a single chunk and treat `fdd7:03d7:6247::%` as `fdd7:03d7:6247:0000:0000:0000:0000:%` or interpret it some other way.  (Sorry, I don't know the answer.)

A second problem is that `/56` splits the middle of some chunk.  I don't know if that can be represented with `%`.

Anyway, here's my best guess:

```
'fdd7:03d7:6247:00%'
```

This confirms PacoHope's contention that leading zeros in each segment are optional:

```
SELECT HEX(INET6_ATON('1111:698:2222::'));
         -->           11110698222200000000000000000000
```

Comment: Sorry, copy and pasted the wrong mask.  I meant /48 which I had been using in my examples that weren't working.  I tried both including the missing zeros options.  If I had been using a /56 that is needed to be `fdd7:03d7:6247:00%`, but I had even tried that unfortunately, and didn't work.

Comment: I would expect `'fdd7:03d7:6247:%'` to work for /48.  And my answer was addressing /120 by mistake.  Doh!

Comment: did you try backticks ` instead of ticks ' ?

Comment: I found MySQL (5.7.23) sensitive to extra leading zeroes. When I used 'username'@'2a05:d011:0698:c100:%' it did not permit a connection from the local subnet, but when I used 'username'@'2a05:d011:698:c100:%' it did work. (Note the 0698 versus 698). I'm a bit of a n00b with respect to ipv6, but I thought that was a valid just like 128.040.020.010 would be a valid (if weird) way to write the ipv4 address 128.40.20.10.

Comment: @PacoHope - IPv4 uses decimal numbers in each of the 4 parts.  IPv6 uses hex in each part.  In `0698` (hex), the `0` represents 4 bits; in `040` the leading zero has no such meaning.  (Nonetheless, I am surprised that 5.7 is sensitive to the leading zero.)

Comment: I understand that, @RickJames (sorry hit enter too soon). But 0698 == 698 == 00000000698 for hexadecimal, no? Infinite leading zeroes shouldn't change anything. It's just like Mac addresses a:b:c is equal to 0a:0b:0c.

Comment: @PacoHope - Your Comment on Feb 11 probably deserves a bug report - bugs.mysql.com .